# Java robot keyboard

Tags: java, keyboard, remote-access, awtrobot

I am trying to make a application in Java, where you can control someones keyboard from a distance, but I am facing a problem. I thought something like this would be possible:

```
            //the message is the key input
            String[] parts = message.split("-");
            String KeyPressed = parts[1];//This is the key that's pressed(for example K)
                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_(KeyPressed));
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
            }
```

But this doesn't work. I know this one works, but you'll have to repeat it for every single key on your keyboard:

```
            //the message is the key input
            String[] parts = message.split("-");
            String KeyPressed = parts[1];
            if(KeyPressed.equals("H")){
                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                }
            }
```

Now my question is, what is the code to do all the keys in a few lines instead of doing the code above for every key on your keyboard?

Comment: Firstly, you only have to create one instance of Robot at the class level. Then your event handlers should be placed within a single event handling loop.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I see no event handlers here

Comment: It's because he needs to implement them. I'm trying to give guidance without writing code for him, which would leave him with working code but no understanding. Your comment, however, does provide a nice entry for the introduction to the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)

Comment: There's no easy way to of this, as KeyEvent.VK_H is used for both "H" and "h", the difference being the state of the shift key. I've used translation tables in the past as the only viable solution, at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to do is implement a KeyListener to receive all keys
here is the event and some examples:
[KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of what the question is asking for. **EDIT:** Oh, now I get it!

Comment: he doesn't have to check every key he wants with a key listener since he will receive e.Key as a property

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the letters A to Z:

`robot.keyPress(KeyPressed);`

But you'll have to use something else for some non-letter keys.

---

A problem is that you are receiving characters as input, but sending key codes as output. This is an unusual translation. It would be easier if you could somehow receive key codes and send them directly... see the answer from Goran for that!

Also, how are you even going to represent keys like Scroll Lock as a character?!

Comment: ah yes - `KeyPressed.charAt(0)` then

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `KeyStroke` for getting key code by `String`, like next :

```
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("H");
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(keyStroke.getKeyCode());
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```